# Flutter - how show unicode character in string?

Tags: flutter, dart, unicode

I need show string with unicode character in my flutter app. This is my code, it is work:

```
var mess = new Runes('hello \u2714');
//('\u2bc8');
return String.fromCharCodes(mess);
```

But it don't work with code '\u2bc8'.
instead of a unicode character, a square.

Also I tried use:

```
 var mess = new Runes('Hello \u{2bc8}');
 return String.fromCharCodes(mess);
```

Result is same.

how do I display this symbol in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose the characters in curly braces

```
var mess = new Runes('hello \u{2714}');
print(new String.fromCharCodes(mess));
```

Have you tried directly this way?

```
return new Text('hello ▶')
```

You can use this unicode `u25B6` also, looks like the one you are trying to show is not recognised for all the fonts, so I recommend you to search the same unicode but recognised by more fonts.

For more info check this [thread](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/special-character-does-not-display-correctly-in-mobile/370639/5)

Comment: Which font are you using? Take a look on this : http://www.unicode-symbol.com/u/2BC8.html